# How to find probability of quantiles given mean and variance?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

If someone could explain the process for beginning this and the formulas involved I would be grateful.

> Male height in the Netherlands is normally distributed with a mean of
>   73 inches and a variance of 16.
>
> a. Find the probability that a randomly selected from the Dutch
>   population male is between 6’6” and 6’2”.
>
> b. Find the probability that a randomly selected male from the Dutch
>   population is between 6”2” and  5’11”.
>
> c. Find the probability that a randomly selected male from the Dutch
>   population is between 5”10“ and 5”6”.

Comment: This is a textbook style question, requiring a `self-study` tag. Please show your work on one or more parts, and be specific about where you need help finishing.

Comment: Please see the discussion of homework-style questions in the [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints and comments:** The parts of the problem are similar. If you understand how to do one of the three parts, you should be able to do the rest. I will try to get you started--without working the problem completely.

The height of a randomly chosen man in this population is $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=72,\sigma=4),$ in *inches.* This seems a bit strange because heights in the Netherlands are ordinarily measured in centimeters.

**In part (a)** you want
$P(74 \le X \le 78)$ or $P(73.5 < X < 78.5),$ depending on the usual conventions in your course. Because you have shown no work, I have no
way to know which convention you are expected to use.

Taking the first interpretation of the problem, you would
standardize the endpoints of the interval of interest, and then use printed tables of the standard normal distribution to
get the final answer:
$$P(74 \le X \le 78) = P\left(\frac{74-\mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{78-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\\
= P\left(\frac{74-\mu}{\sigma} \le Z \le \frac{78-\mu}{\sigma}\right) =\, ?$$
where $Z$ is standard normal. Plug in the numerical values for $\mu$ and 
$\sigma,$ and use the printed table to finish the problem. [If you haven't used normal tables before, see if you can find an example of their use in your textbook.]

If you use R statistical software, you get the following numerical results. Your answer from printed tables may be a little different because of the rounding involved in using the tables. (The second computation in R refers to the second possible  convention for formulating the problem, mentioned above.)

```
diff(pnorm(c(74,78), 72, 4))
[1] 0.2417303
diff(pnorm(c(73.5,78.5), 72, 4))
[1] 0.301749
```

In the figure below, the probability you seek is represented by the area
under the density curve between the two vertical dotted lines.

[image]